# Similarity classes of a $7 \times 7$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ represented by matrices with entries from $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I'm working on the following problem, and have everything figured out just fine, but I'm not even sure what the last part of this problem is asking me to find.  Here's the problem:
Let $A$ be a $7 \times 7$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ with $f_A(x) = (x^2+1)^2(x^3-2)$.

a) What is the trace and determinate of $A$?

b) What are the possibilities for $A$ up to similarity?  For each class, give exactly one matrix.

c) Which of these classes are represented by matrices with entries from $\mathbb{Q}$?  In each such case, give a corresponding matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

So from part b) I know there are $4$ possible similarity classes, as there are (up to a permutation matrix) $4$ possible Jordan canonical forms of $A$.  However, I'm not sure what c) is asking for.  In $2$ out of the $4$ cases, the minimal polynomial $m_A \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, so is the answer simply just $2$, or is it asking for something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of the rational canonical form (or Frobenius normal form)?

Comment: Yes, I've only seen it once however @BrauerSuzuki.

Comment: The rational canonical form allows you to write down a matrix with given minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial. Basically, you only need to understand companion matrices.